# change $_POST content without refresh page?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

I have a page with dynamic content and a button to save as PDF.
I send via ajax the content to my php file.

The problem is that my application never refresh.

If I change the content on page, and then press save pdf button, the content of $_POST never change until page refresh.

Someone know how I can do to avoid this?

Ajax request into Jquery event on button click.

```
$(document).on("click", "#saveAll", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var nombre = 'savedImageData'+Math.random();
  var overviewLoad = '';
  var programsLoad = '';
  var barriersLoad = '';
  var rolesLoad = '';
  var relationsLoad = '';
  var printcont = '';
  $('#printall').html('');
  overviewLoad = $("#orgoverview").html();
  programsLoad = $("#orgprograms").html();
  barriersLoad = $("#orgbarriers").html();
  rolesLoad = $("#orgroles").html();


   var src1 = $("#canvasImg").attr("src");
   relationsLoad = $("#orgrelations").html();
   var rolestoles = $('#orgroles').html();
  $('#printall').append(overviewLoad);
  $('#printall').append('<div class="page">');
  $('#printall').append(programsLoad+'</div>');
  $('#printall').append('<div class="page">');
  $('#printall').append(barriersLoad+'</div>');
  $('#printall').append('<div class="page">');
  $('#printall').append(relationsLoad+'</div>');
  $('#printall').append('<div class="page">');
  $('#printall').append(rolestoles+'</div>');
  printcont = $('#printall').html();



  $('<input>').attr('value', '');
  $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'contenido',
    id: 'contenido',
    value: printcont 
}).prependTo('form#getPDF');
  $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "run/runpdf.php?"+Math.random(),
            data: $("form#getPDF").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            success: function(someMessageFromPhp) {
                mystring = someMessageFromPhp.replace('../','');
                window.open(mystring+'?'+Math.random());
                $('#downloadPDF').hide(); 
            }
        });



  });
```

Php

```
    <?php
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', true);

// include DOMPDF's default configuration
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
$contenido .= utf8_encode($_POST['contenido']);
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper('LETTER', 'portrait');
$dompdf->load_html($contenido);
$dompdf->render();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $output);
?>
```

Comment: How you post via ajax or php ?

Comment: Hi @KarthikKeyan Thanks for your response.

`$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "run/runpdf.php?"+Math.random(),
                data: $("form#getPDF").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                success: function(someMessageFromPhp) {
                    mystring = someMessageFromPhp.replace('../','');
                    window.open(mystring+'?'+Math.random());
                    $('#downloadPDF').hide(); 
                }
            });
`

Comment: I think ajax function is not call properly

Comment: @KarthikKeyan This ajax request send to php page a hidden input with the content. 
I'm catch this content via POST, once pdf is generated, send the url of pdf as ajax response and open it into new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
Instead of send via POST form input content, I've passed as data in ajax a variable with loaded html to pass.

```
printcont = $('#printall').html();

      $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'run/runpdf.php?'+Math.random(),
            data: {'contenido': printcont},
            cache: false,
            success: function(someMessageFromPhp) {
               mystring = 'run/'+someMessageFromPhp;
               window.open(mystring+'?'+Math.random());
               $('#downloadPDF').hide();
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your time, for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourUrl',
  success: function(data){
    yourHTMLInputsOrWhatEver = data;
}
});
```

the success method is called when the result form your ajax call was sent to the client. this should work alone. If you wanna force a refresh, use `document.location.reload();` inside the success callback.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79893/discussion-on-answer-by-messerbill-change-post-content-without-refresh-page).